# How to add all repeating parameter into a single array?

Tags: php

I have a query which has some recurring params, how can I pick the recurring params and put them in an array?

For example: `fruit=apple&fruit=banana&fruit=oranges&shopper=tom`

Comment: check [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: I have, it actually outputs the same query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$str = "fruit=apple&fruit=banana&fruit=oranges&shopper=tom";
$str = str_replace('fruit', 'fruit[]', $str);
parse_str($str, $output);
print_r($output['fruit']);
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect - will tick the answer when the time is up.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative code examples appended: (i) doing it via form (ii) doing it via iteration and manipulation

```
<form action="test1234.php" method="GET">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" />apple<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="banana" />banana<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange" />orange<br />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="buyer[]" value="tom" />tom<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="buyer[]" value="dick" />dick<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="buyer[]" value="harry" />harry<br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<br />

<?php

var_dump($_GET); // (i) doing it via form

echo '<br /><br /><hr />';

$str = 'fruit=apple&fruit=banana&fruit=oranges&shopper=tom';

$key_value_pair_arr = explode('&', $str);

$result = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($key_value_pair_arr); $i++){

    $key_value = explode('=', $key_value_pair_arr[$i]);

    $key = $key_value[0];
    $value = $key_value[1];

    $result[$key][] = $value;
}

var_dump($result); // (ii) doing it via iteration and manipulation
?>
```